# delphi - лог EOracleError ошибок с ApplicationEvents

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Хочу сохранять все ошибки в бд. Проблема возникает при возникновении EOracleError ошибки, т.к. тогда в message нет информации ни о строке возникновении ошибки ни о датасете.

Для перехвата ошибок использую компонент TApplicationEvents:

```
procedure TfrmMain.ApplicationEvents1Exception(Sender: TObject;
  E: Exception);
begin
dmMain.oqLog.SetVariable(':V_ERROR', e.ToString);
dmMain.oqLog.Execute;
end;
```

Для теста вызываю ошибку no_data_found выполнением запроса:

```
begin
raise no_data_found;
end;
```

В результате в e.ToString имею: **ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 2**. Строка e.StackTrace вообще пустая.

Как получить имя датасета, формы и строки в которых возникла ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте madExcept. Он может писать логи с исключений и многое другое.

Comment: А не подскажите ли можно в madExcept скрыть окошко с сообщением что произошла ошибка? нужно сделать это незаметным для пользователя.

Comment: Да, конечно можно.

Answer (score 1):

Я делала отдельный метод для выполнения запроса TOracleDataSet. Реализация, правда, на CBuilder, но разница небольшая. Номер строки в запросе не выводится.

```
bool ExecuteSQL( TOracleQuery* Q ) 
//В качестве входного параметра может быть TOracleDataSet
{
AnsiString StringError = "";
TOracleSession* OS = Q->Session;
TCheckConnectionResult Result;
 Q->Close();
try{
    //Сначала проверяем связь с БД
    if ( OS )
        Result = Q->Session->CheckConnection( true );
    else
    {
        MesBoxErr("Не установлено соединение с базой данных");
        return false;
    }

} catch ( Exception & E ) {
    MesBoxErr( "Ошибка подключения к базе данных");
    return false;
}
if ( Result == ccError ) {
    MesBoxErr( "Потеряно соединение с базой данных." );
    return false;
}

//если связь с БД есть проверяем запрос
    try {

        Q->Execute() ; //Если TOracleDataSet, то Q->Open();

     } catch ( Exception & E ) {
        StringError = "При выполнении запроса " + Q->Name + "\n";
        StringError += Q->SQL + "\n";
        MesBoxErr( ( StringError + "возникла ошибка:\n" + E.Message  ).c_str() );
        return false;
    }
  }

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Концепция записи *каждой ошибки* в БД в условно-реальном времени – неверная. Такая реализация держит в постоянном "напряжении" сетевое соединение, что в итоге влияет на производительность приложения. Кроме того, если это "разнесёнка" (то есть сервер БД где-нибудь далеко в Интернете), то возможны серьёзные задержки, очереди и прочая непредсказуемость.

Я в своих приложениях реализую запись логов сначала в локальный файл, а затем, при достижении файлом определённого количества строк, делаю шиппинг лога в базу. Причём, делает это отдельный поток, который на время приостанавливает запись, шиппит лог, а затем создаёт новый.

Лог можно вести в XML или в tab-delimited формате.

Comment: Это хороший комментарий к вопросу, но к сожалению не ответ.

Comment: С одной стороны это не ответ на конкретный вопрос – верно. Но с другой... Возможно совет заставит задуматься над архитектурой. Да и оформить этот совет в виде комментария было бы сложно.

Comment: У комментария лимит в 600 символов - вполне достаточно. Тем более, что вопрос "Как получить имя датасета, формы и строки в которых возникла ошибка?", а запись в БД, в данном случае, вторична.